# combine the similar values of a column into rows

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have  a column with userIds, but I want to change this column into different rows and combine the  [same values in one row.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90AFs.png)

Code to produce the data in the image looks like:

```
userid <- c(415,375,415,415,513,64,375,415,317,375)
rating <- c(4,4,4,5,5,4,3,5,4,5)
title <- c("GoldenEye (1995)","GoldenEye (1995)","Babe (1995)",
           "Usual Suspects, The (1995)", "Braveheart (1995)","Braveheart (1995)","Braveheart (1995)",
           "Braveheart (1995)","Apollo 13 (1995)","Apollo 13 (1995)")

data <- data.frame(userid,rating,title)
```

How do I transform the data so the movie titles are columns, with one row per userid, where the ratings are the cells of the data frame?

```
  userid Apollo 13 (1995) Babe (1995) Braveheart (1995) GoldenEye (1995)
1     64               NA          NA                 4               NA
2    317                4          NA                NA               NA
3    375                5          NA                 3                4
4    415               NA           4                 5                4
5    513               NA          NA                 5               NA
  Usual Suspects, The (1995)
1                         NA
2                         NA
3                         NA
4                          5
5                         NA
>
```

Comment: Please make sure your question adheres to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) format. That enables us to help you.

Comment: Hello Rodaina. Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on what your desired output is? Do you want to transform the data so each row is a movie name, and the columns are the userids? Also, on SO it is helpful to post a question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so people can provide answers that include working code and data.

Comment: I want the rows to be the userIds and columns to be the names of the movies, and then I want to fill this matrix with the ratings of each movie with the corresponding user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you didn't gave us a example database, I created a little one. I believe this solve your problem:

```
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)

movies = data.table(userid = c(21, 24, 35, 21, 27, 35, 21),    
                    movie = c("titanic","titanic", "titanic", "cinderella", "cinderella", "cinderella", "big hero"), 
                    rating = c(1,3,4,2,1,5,3))

movies = spread(movies, key = movie, value = rating)
```

Hope it helps!